# ADVI on pymc3 on gpu

Tags: neural-network, pymc3

Following this example: 
http://twiecki.github.io/blog/2016/07/05/bayesian-deep-learning/, the network can be trained on the gpu using float32 values for each variable.

Strangely though, if more layers get passed to the neural net (for example 5 layers with 800 neurons each) or when the number of neurons is set to higher values using less layers, I get an error message like this:

> 0%|          | 1/50000 [00:00<6:47:16,  2.05it/s]Traceback (most recent >call last):
>
> File "/opt/pycharm-community-2016.3.2/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1596, >in 
>      globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
>
> File "/opt/pycharm-community-2016.3.2/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 974, in >run
>      pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
>
> File "/home/d1211/PycharmProjects/BNN/withLasagne.py", line 342, in 
>      v_params, trace, ppc, y_pred = run_advi(likelihood)
>
> File "/home/d1211/PycharmProjects/BNN/withLasagne.py", line 299, in >run_advi
>      total_size=total_size, learning_rate=1e-2, epsilon=1.0
>
> File "/home/d1211/pythonpath/lib/python/Theano-0.9.0-py2.7.egg/theano/configparser.py", line 117, in res
>      return f(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/home/d1211/pythonpath/lib/python/pymc3-3.1rc3-py2.7.egg/pymc3/variational/advi_minibatch.py", line 528, in advi_minibatch
>
> raise FloatingPointError('NaN occurred in ADVI optimization.')
>
> FloatingPointError: NaN occurred in ADVI optimization.

On the other hand, when using float64 variables there is no error.

So I guess the number of variables that have to be stored is too big, but I don't understand how this is connected to float32/float64-values, which are just a mean of precision.

Can you please help me understand this?

Comment: Shame on me, the weights from my huge layers to the output of 10 neurons were too small to be computed by float32 integers.

So there's no problem at all

Answer (score 1):

Shame on me, the weights from my huge layers to the output of 10 neurons were too small to be computed by float32 integers. So there's no problem at all